# Is it better to scan through an XML variable or create temporary table?

Tags: sql, xml, performance, optimization

I have an stored procedure accepting an XML parameter. As of now, my current implementation is that I scan through the nodes  of that XML all through out the body of my SP using this method:

```
SELECT
tbl.col.value('col1[1]', 'varchar(100)') as colA
tbl.col.value('col1[2]', 'varchar(100)') as colB
tbl.col.value('col1[3]', 'varchar(100)') as colC
tbl.col.value('col1[4]', 'varchar(100)') as colD
FROM @xmLInput.nodes('//root/elem1') as tbl(col)
```

Now I'm looking into optimizing my SP. A friend of mine suggested to store all values of @xmlInput in a table, and use that table all through out my SP instead of using SELECT in @xmlInput for the rest of my SP.

Do you guys think it would be better to have it on a temporary table?

Comment: Have you tried measuring the 2 different approaches? Using the Executionplans?

Comment: Yeah I did but I'm getting variable result, may be because there's a number of users using the same server. But I honestly think that having a temporary table would be more costly, what do you think?

Comment: I would rather lean towards such a temp table, as the cost might be high for extracting XML. That said, it will also depend on the number of "rows" in the XML, if it is not a lot, I dont see that the overhead will be that much. What I would say though is that placing it in a temp table, will also reduce the redundancy of the code to get it from the XML.

Comment: Thanks astrander, as for the number of rows in the XML, it's usually like 50 or less rows. Yeah I think that's a good idea for redundancy reduction's sake.  Thanks a lot astrander :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try it both ways. I did in my code, and found that the XML was 8x faster than a temporary table. I also tried dynamically generating the query with everything as constants, and that was another 10x faster than the XML.